# Relying on "mysql_insert_id"

Tags: php, mysql

Think a table called as `foo`, which has `id (PRIMARY & AUTO_INCREMENT)` column. I'm inserting a row to this table and challenge starts at this point.

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `foo` (id, row1, ...) VALUES('', '$row1', ...)");
if (!$db->is_error && $db->last_insert_id) {
   $id = $db->last_insert_id;
   do_really_important_things_with_last_ID($id);
   do_another_important_things_with_last_ID($id);
   ...
   do_ ... with_last_ID($id);
   do_ ... with_last_ID($id);
}
```

I'm calling it immediately after insert query and using exactly current connection link while getting `last_insert_id`, but do not know how does it matter(?).

```
$this->dbh = @mysql_connect(.....);
...
// query function
$this->result = @mysql_query($query, $this->dbh);
...
if (preg_match("/insert/i", $query)) {
   $this->last_insert_id = @mysql_insert_id($this->dbh);
}
```

**Should I worry about this implementation relying on `mysql_insert_id`?**

Answer (score 5):

last_insert_id should be a function, that will return inserted id

```
function last_insert_id(){
 return @mysql_insert_id();
}

if (!$db->is_error && $db->last_insert_id()) {
   $id = $db->last_insert_id();
   do_really_important_things_with_last_ID($id);
   do_another_important_things_with_last_ID($id);
   ...
   do_ ... with_last_ID($id);
   do_ ... with_last_ID($id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Hemant; But I'm storing `$this->last_insert_id` immediately in `$db->query()` function "if `$query` contains `INSERT` keyword".

Comment: try by skip using id field in query

Answer (score 5):

Look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/getting-unique-id.html for more information, it says this:

> "For LAST_INSERT_ID(), the most recently generated ID is maintained in
>   the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client. It is not even changed if you update another AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not NULL and
>   not 0). Using LAST_INSERT_ID() and AUTO_INCREMENT columns
>   simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client
>   will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement that client
>   executed."

So you should be fine doing what you want and you shouldn't get strange results.

Answer (score 3):

@Anton is correct. Wanted to add the following.

> When used in transactions, mysql_insert_id() MUST be called before
>   committing. Otherwise, it will return unpredictable results.

Courtesy http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php